# Powershell_script resource throws error: "Your session has expired, please login again."

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, perforce

I am trying to use Chef to pull a file from Perforce, by calling `p4 sync` from a PowerShell script.  As the title indicates, I am being plagued with this failure: "Your session has expired, please login again."  From what I have gathered, it has something to do with the way the PowerShell script is run through Chef (using `Invoke-Command`?)

Here's what I have that is *not* working :(

```
powershell_script 'P4Sync' do
    cwd "C:\\Program Files\\Perforce"
    code <<-EOH
        &".\\p4.exe" set P4PORT=server:1234
        &".\\p4.exe" set P4USER=AUTOMATION_USER
        set shallNotPass 'AUTOMATION_USER_PASSWORD_TICKET'
        &".\\p4.exe" -d c:\\temp -P $shallNotPass client -o | &".\\p4.exe" -P $shallNotPass client -i
        set  rootdir '//root/scripts'
        &".\\p4.exe" -P $shallNotPass sync $rootdir/script.bat
        &".\\p4.exe" -P $shallNotPass sync $rootdir/script.sh
    EOH
end
```

The other powershell_script resources that I have used (which *are* working) involve only PowerShell cmdlets, and not external executables.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!  Also, if you care to share any other resources where I might have found this information on my own, it would also be helpful.  I've spent quite a bit of time hunting the internet on this error, and haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a Perforce authentication failure and suggests there's a problem with your AUTOMATION_USER_PASSWORD_TICKET.  If that's actually a ticket (it should look like a hash rather than plaintext), the problem is most likely that it's expired -- by default a login ticket is only valid for 12 hours after the "p4 login" command used to acquire it.

See the documentation for "p4 login" for more on how tickets work:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_login.html

The easiest solution is probably to put AUTOMATION_USER in a group with an unlimited Timeout, then re-run "p4 login" to get a new ticket (which will never expire) and put that in your script.

Comment: Thanks Sam!  That seems to have been the problem.  I should have considered that, but I had forgotten about the ticket timeout.  I guess I probably couldn't find anything on this because I was looking for powershell errors and not P4 errors~